# How to see how all objects with Decimate modifier will look like?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects

I want to add Decimate modifier to all objects, but I need for one project to have all objects separate from each other, so I can't merge them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, is there any way other than adding Decimate modifier to each object separately. Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: If your objects are separate and you want to see what the Decimate do on each one, you need to give the Decimate to each one, not sure to completely understand your question though...

Comment: You can copy the modifier to each object by clicking on the down facing arrow in the right of the field and choosing "Copy to selected"

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate all objects to be safe, then join them, then add the modifier. If you still want the decimated objects separate, go into edit, select all, then Mesh > Separate > By loose parts. This will make them separate again.